# Repeated number in sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, hashtable

I was asked this question recently in an interview :

What is the most efficient way to find a repeated number in a sorted array?

My answer was based on using a hash table with key as array element and number of repetitions in array as value; iterate the array and update hash table. In the end, hash table can be checked for elements with count > 1 ; those are the repeated elements.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: if the difference between adjacent elements in array is at most 1, you can do it with binary search in O(log(n)) time, checking for `a[i]-a[0]<i`. Otherwise you have to search along the array for `a[i]==a[i+1]`, getting O(n) time. You're asked for "a number" so just one will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do this with space of `O(1)`. Since its a sorted array, all you need to do it to subtract the current number with the next one. If the result is `0` then you have a repeated number.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the hash table will be more useful for an unsorted array, right ?

Comment: It all depends on what the interviewer expects. Such questions have a variety of answers. Example, you can use a byte array instead of a hashMap here which will save space but will not be of `O(1)` space. I would suggest you to ask more questions to the interviewer about what he/she is expecting before answering the question.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: How? `1 - (-1) != 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Check every element in the array (except the last one) with the next element, if they're equal then stop and exit: you've found a repeated element. It works because the array is sorted, it doesn't require any additional space and in the worst case (no repeated elements) it'll be O(n), because all of the array will have to be traversed.

Answer (score 0):

-Sort the Array

-find the difference between adjacent indices values

-if the difference is 0 then there is a repeat and note the indices

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int searchrepeativeVal(int a[]){

    int left =0;
    int right= a.length;
    int mid;

    while (right-left>1){

        mid= (left+right)/2;

        if(a[mid]!=mid+1){
            if(a[mid]== mid){
                return mid;
            }else{
                right=mid;
            }
        }else{

            if(a[mid]==mid ){
                return mid;
            }else{
                left =mid;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7